# Link Test to TestCase WorkItem

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild

I’d like to know if there is a way to really link the test of a build, with a test case WorkItem.

I've seen that you can attach the result of a test to a test case, but I want the test (method) to be linked to the test case, not the result.

I’m using Report Builder, where I show the list of test result of a build. The thing is, the name of each tests comes from the methods name. I’d prefer to use the name of the test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot link a part of code (in this case a test method) to an work item (in this case a test case).